# Partial De-duplication in R based on string value match

Tags: r, string, duplicates, matching, fuzzy

I have a dataframe  named 'reviews' like this:

```
score_phrase    title   score   release_year    release_month   release_day
```

1   Amazing LittleBigPlanet PS Vita 9   2012    9   12
2   Amazing LittleBigPlanet PS Vita -- Marvel Super Hero Edition    9   2012    9   12
3   Great   Splice: Tree of Life    8.5 2012    9   12
4   Great   NHL 13  8.5 2012    9   11
5   Great   NHL 13  8.5 2012    9   11
6   Good    Total War Battles: Shogun   7   2012    9   11
7   Awful   Double Dragon: Neon 3   2012    9   11
8   Amazing Guild Wars 2    9   2012    9   11
9   Awful   Double Dragon: Neon 3   2012    9   11
10  Good    Total War Battles: Shogun   7   2012    9   11

Objective: Slight mismatch/typo in column values cause duplication in records. Here Row 1 and Row 2 are duplicates and Row 2 should be dropped after de-duplication.

I used `dedup()` function of 'SCRUBR' package to perform de-duplication but on a large dataset, I get incorrect number of duplicates when I toggle tolerance level for string matching.

For example:

```
partial_dup_data <- reviews[1:100,] %>% dedup(tolerance = 0.7) 
#count w/o duplicates: 90
attr(partial_dup_data, "dups") 
# count of identified duplicates: 16
```

Could somebody suggest what I am doing incorrectly? Is there another approach to achieve the objective?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. Fuzzy-matching on strings is just by definition, "fuzzy." You could look into various string-distance packages which deal with this sort of issue. All probabilistic matching has a 'grey area' where results are unclear. Often the solution is manual human intervention for the difficult cases.

Comment: also please provide us minimal reproducible example so that we can help you further

Comment: I used the dataset available at Kaggle.  Data set : ign.csv
https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/data-cleaning-challenge-deduplication/data